# calculating sample variance with arraylists Java

Tags: java

I'm doing an exercise where you have to calculate variance using arraylists in java.

I thought maybe having separate calculation methods for the arraylist with doubles rather than integers would help but it didn't.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Variance {
    // Copy here sum from exercise 63 
    public static double sum(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        int i = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        while (i < list.size()) {
            sum += list.get(i);
            i++;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    public static double sumdouble(ArrayList<Double> list) {
        int i = 0;
        double sum = 0;

        while (i < list.size()) {
            sum += list.get(i);
            i++;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    // Copy here average from exercise 64 
      public static double average(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        double sum = sum(list);
        double average = sum / list.size();
        return average;
    }

         public static double averagedouble(ArrayList<Double> lists) {
        double sum = sumdouble(lists);
        double average = sum / lists.size();
        return average;
    }

    public static double variance(ArrayList<Integer> list) {


        double mean = average(list);
        int i = list.size() - 1;
        ArrayList<Double> varianceList = new ArrayList<Double>();


        while (i >= 0) {
            //gets value

            double value = list.get(i);
            value = value - mean;
            value = value * value;
            varianceList.add(value);


        }

        double final = averagedouble(varianceList);

        return final;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(3);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(2);

        System.out.println("The variance is: " + variance(list));
    }

}
```

> Error in netbeans: incompatible types: ArrayList cannot be
>   converted to double

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your while loop never ends, and this `double final = averagedouble(varianceList);` won't compile since `final` is a Java key word.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is all in the variance method. 
You need the decrement in the loop `--i;`
And you have to rename your return variable to something else, or simply return the value directly. Your method should instead be:

```
public static double variance(ArrayList<Integer> list) {

    double mean = average(list);
    int i = list.size() - 1;
    ArrayList<Double> varianceList = new ArrayList<Double>();


    while (i >= 0) {
        //gets value

        double value = list.get(i);
        value = value - mean;
        value = value * value;
        varianceList.add(value);
        --i;

    }

    return averagedouble(varianceList);
}
```

Also i would consider switching most of your while loops to for loops because they are more suited to loop through an entire array.

Answer (score 0):

You missed to decrement the loop, `--i;` is missing in the code.

Use this code, it is optimized and clean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Variance 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers;
    int size;
    public Variance(ArrayList<Integer> listOfIntegers) 
    {
        this.listOfIntegers = listOfIntegers;
        size = listOfIntegers.size();
    }   

    double getMean()
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for(double a : listOfIntegers)
           sum += a;
        return sum/size;
    }

    double getVariance()
    {
        double mean = getMean();
        double square = 0;
        for(double a :listOfIntegers)
            square += (a-mean)*(a-mean);
        return square/size;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are datatype declaring mistakes in your methods:

```
public static double sum(ArrayList<Integer> list)
```

this should return `int` to be compatible with `int` variable `sum` and elements datatype of ArrayList:

```
public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> list)
```

also in this method :

```
public static double average(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        //double sum = sum(list);
        int sum = sum(list);
        double average = sum / list.size();
        return average;
}
```

You should declare `sum` as `int` to be compatible with return type of `sum()` method.

Another problem while loop in `variance` method is infinite you need to fix it:

```
while (i >= 0) {
    //gets value
double value = list.get(i);
       value = value - mean;
       value = value * value;
       varianceList.add(value);
       i--;  // decrease i index 
}
```

and at return statement variable shouldn't be a reserved keyword in java `final`

instead you can rename it or just return the value of method:

`return averagedouble(varianceList);`

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Variance {

```
public static int sum(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    int sum=0;
    for(int i:list){
        sum+=i;
    }



    return sum;
}


public static double average(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    double size = list.size();
    return(1.0*sum(list)/size);

}

public static double variance(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
    // write code here

    double asq=0.0;
    for(int i:list){
        asq = asq + Math.pow((i-average(list)),2);
    }
    double var = asq/(list.size()) ;
    return var;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(3);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(7);
    list.add(2);

    System.out.println("The variance is: " + variance(list));
}
```

}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.